# How to declare global variable in parent layout in Yii

Tags: layout, yii, view, global

So I have a parent layout called "font.php" which is located in "protected>views>layouts". What I would love to be able to do is to add PHP code at the top of this file so that all subsequent child views can access it.

I've tried declaring `globals` but they do not work, I've also tried `define()` and that does not work. Is there a simple way to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your both layout and view you have `$this`, which is instance of current controller. The simpliest way is to add some properties to controller and access them from layout and child views.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding a global variable in your layout file, the short answer is no. Your layout file wraps the view file after the fact, it isn't called before hand.